# Change values in a static template

Tags: html, vue.js

Here is a basic setup for what I would like to do:

**HTML Side**

*test.html*

```
<div id="app">
    <my-comp temp="1" cat="{ name:'Geoff', age:3 }"></my-comp>
</div>
```

**Vue Side**

*app.js:*

```
import myComp from './components/myComp.vue'

app = new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    components: {
        myComp
    }
});
```

*myComp.vue*

```
<template>
    <div v-html='template'>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        props: [
            'temp',
            'cat'
        ],
        data () {
            temp1: `<input name="name" value="cat.name">
                    <input name="age" value="cat.age">`,
            // other template
            // ...

        },
        computed: {
            template() {
                return this.temp == 1 ? this.temp1 : this.temp2;
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My problem is when I open the html file in the browser, I get:

```
cat.name
cat.age
```

appearing in the input. Technically, my form isn't responsive to existing data. How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test.html you have to change this:

```
<my-comp :temp="1" :cat="{ name:'Geoff', age:3 }"></my-comp>
```

The double dots have to added otherwise it will be interpreted as an string and not as an object.

With `value` you are on the right track. The only you have to change is this because you want to insert a variable into your 'string'

```
  data() {
    return {
      temp1: `<input name="name" value="${this.cat.name}">
              <input name="age" value="${this.cat.age}">`
    }
  }
```

Comment: Oh...I made an mistake...sorry. Give me one minute to update my answer

Comment: Tryin' again, gosh darnit!

Answer (score -1):

Don't forget to add 'input type' as well.

Comment: The `type` attribute is optional.